# How to connect Odoo 13 with PostgreSQL database?

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo, odoo-13

I am using Windows 10, PostgreSQL 12, Python 3.7.5 . I create username `odoo`, password `odoo`, create database `mydb`.

Source code is https://github.com/odoo/odoo/tree/aa0554d224337e1d966479a351a3ed059d297765

I run command

```
python odoo-bin -r odoo -w odoo --addons-path=addons --db-filter=mydb$
```

Error

```
E:\source_code\github.com\xxxxxxxx\odoo>python odoo-bin -r odoo -w odoo --addons-path=addons --db-filter=mydb$
2019-11-11 09:20:31,240 7372 INFO ? odoo: Odoo version 13.0
2019-11-11 09:20:31,240 7372 INFO ? odoo: addons paths: ['E:\\source_code\\github.com\\xxxxxxxx\\odoo\\odoo\\addons', 'c:\\users\\xxxxxxxx\\appdata\\local\\openerp s.a\\odoo\\addons\\13.0', 'e:\\source_code\\github.com\\xxxxxxxx\\odoo\\addons', 'e:\\source_code\\github.com\\xxxxxxxx\\odoo\\odoo\\addons']
2019-11-11 09:20:31,241 7372 INFO ? odoo: database: odoo@default:default
2019-11-11 09:20:31,397 7372 INFO ? odoo.addons.base.models.ir_actions_report: You need Wkhtmltopdf to print a pdf version of the reports.
2019-11-11 09:20:31,517 7372 INFO ? odoo.service.server: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on D1CMPS_VyDN.mptelecom.com:8069
2019-11-11 09:20:45,250 7372 INFO ? odoo.http: HTTP Configuring static files
2019-11-11 09:20:45,296 7372 INFO ? odoo.sql_db: Connection to the database failed
2019-11-11 09:20:45,299 7372 INFO ? werkzeug: 192.168.50.215 - - [11/Nov/2019 09:20:45] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 - 0 0.000 0.039
2019-11-11 09:20:45,333 7372 ERROR ? werkzeug: Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 270, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 258, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "E:\source_code\github.com\xxxxxxxx\odoo\odoo\service\server.py", line 414, in app
    return self.app(e, s)
  File "E:\source_code\github.com\xxxxxxxx\odoo\odoo\service\wsgi_server.py", line 142, in application
    return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
  File "E:\source_code\github.com\xxxxxxxx\odoo\odoo\service\wsgi_server.py", line 117, in application_unproxied
    result = odoo.http.root(environ, start_response)
  File "E:\source_code\github.com\xxxxxxxx\odoo\odoo\http.py", line 1281, in __call__
    return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)
  File "E:\source_code\github.com\xxxxxxxx\odoo\odoo\http.py", line 1251, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\wsgi.py", line 766, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "E:\source_code\github.com\xxxxxxxx\odoo\odoo\http.py", line 1415, in dispatch
    self.setup_db(httprequest)
  File "E:\source_code\github.com\xxxxxxxx\odoo\odoo\http.py", line 1338, in setup_db
    httprequest.session.db = db_monodb(httprequest)
  File "E:\source_code\github.com\xxxxxxxx\odoo\odoo\http.py", line 1499, in db_monodb
    dbs = db_list(True, httprequest)
  File "E:\source_code\github.com\xxxxxxxx\odoo\odoo\http.py", line 1466, in db_list
    dbs = odoo.service.db.list_dbs(force)
  File "E:\source_code\github.com\xxxxxxxx\odoo\odoo\service\db.py", line 378, in list_dbs
    with closing(db.cursor()) as cr:
  File "E:\source_code\github.com\xxxxxxxx\odoo\odoo\sql_db.py", line 649, in cursor
    return Cursor(self.__pool, self.dbname, self.dsn, serialized=serialized)
  File "E:\source_code\github.com\xxxxxxxx\odoo\odoo\sql_db.py", line 186, in __init__
    self._cnx = pool.borrow(dsn)
  File "E:\source_code\github.com\xxxxxxxx\odoo\odoo\sql_db.py", line 532, in _locked
    return fun(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\source_code\github.com\xxxxxxxx\odoo\odoo\sql_db.py", line 600, in borrow
    **connection_info)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 126, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  role "odoo" is not permitted to log in - - -
2019-11-11 09:20:45,442 7372 INFO ? odoo.sql_db: Connection to the database failed
2019-11-11 09:20:45,443 7372 INFO ? werkzeug: 192.168.50.215 - - [11/Nov/2019 09:20:45] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 - 0 0.000 0.057
2019-11-11 09:20:45,449 7372 ERROR ? werkzeug: Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 270, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 258, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "E:\source_code\github.com\xxxxxxxx\odoo\odoo\service\server.py", line 414, in app
    return self.app(e, s)
  File "E:\source_code\github.com\xxxxxxxx\odoo\odoo\service\wsgi_server.py", line 142, in application
    return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
  File "E:\source_code\github.com\xxxxxxxx\odoo\odoo\service\wsgi_server.py", line 117, in application_unproxied
    result = odoo.http.root(environ, start_response)
  File "E:\source_code\github.com\xxxxxxxx\odoo\odoo\http.py", line 1281, in __call__
    return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)
  File "E:\source_code\github.com\xxxxxxxx\odoo\odoo\http.py", line 1251, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\wsgi.py", line 766, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "E:\source_code\github.com\xxxxxxxx\odoo\odoo\http.py", line 1415, in dispatch
    self.setup_db(httprequest)
  File "E:\source_code\github.com\xxxxxxxx\odoo\odoo\http.py", line 1338, in setup_db
    httprequest.session.db = db_monodb(httprequest)
  File "E:\source_code\github.com\xxxxxxxx\odoo\odoo\http.py", line 1499, in db_monodb
    dbs = db_list(True, httprequest)
  File "E:\source_code\github.com\xxxxxxxx\odoo\odoo\http.py", line 1466, in db_list
    dbs = odoo.service.db.list_dbs(force)
  File "E:\source_code\github.com\xxxxxxxx\odoo\odoo\service\db.py", line 378, in list_dbs
    with closing(db.cursor()) as cr:
  File "E:\source_code\github.com\xxxxxxxx\odoo\odoo\sql_db.py", line 649, in cursor
    return Cursor(self.__pool, self.dbname, self.dsn, serialized=serialized)
  File "E:\source_code\github.com\xxxxxxxx\odoo\odoo\sql_db.py", line 186, in __init__
    self._cnx = pool.borrow(dsn)
  File "E:\source_code\github.com\xxxxxxxx\odoo\odoo\sql_db.py", line 532, in _locked
    return fun(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\source_code\github.com\xxxxxxxx\odoo\odoo\sql_db.py", line 600, in borrow
    **connection_info)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 126, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  role "odoo" is not permitted to log in - - -
```

How to start Odoo 13 success from source code?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to configure the DB to trust your IP address:

make the following chages in `pg_hba.conf`:

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host all all 127.0.0.1/32   trust
host all all MY_IP/24 trust
```

see also [this](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/setup/install.html#id3)

Answer (score 1):

To [create a PostgreSQL user](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/setup/install.html#postgresql), follow these steps:

1. Add PostgreSQL’s `bin` directory (by default: `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\<version>\bin`) to
   your `PATH`.
2. Create a postgres user with a password using the pg admin gui:

   - Open **pgAdminIII**.
   - Double-click the server to create a connection.
   - Select Edit ‣ New Object ‣ New Login Role.
   - Enter the username in the **Role Name** field (e.g. `odoo`).
   - Open the **Definition** tab and enter the password (e.g. `odoo`), then click **OK**.

Answer (score 0):

odoo 13 a default user name odoo that user with postgress it use a recently db created.

you can pass a database configuration on your config file

odoo 13  /debian/odoo.conf

```
[options]
; This is the password that allows database operations:
; admin_passwd = admin
db_host = False
db_port = False
db_user = odoo
db_password = False
;addons_path = /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons
```

you can set db host port user password and use it